# Fetch Data from Database without Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am pretty new with Node JS so I am bit lost. I am building a website that will pull data from a a mysql database. I would like to have this data refresh every 10 minutes and pull the updated values from a mysql database.

What is the best way for me to query the database again and display the updates values on the page using Express JS and Handlebars?

Comment: pouchDb database is suitable for this, there is live refresh implemented.

Comment: I believe that you'll need to use websockets if you need a live display of the data.

Comment: I would try with Socket.io and some Node cron which would send data to clients.

Comment: So lets say my index.html page loads. Whats the best way to just do a mysql query and show that data?